# Am driving Mazda Bongo Brawny, automatic. won't shift gears and when on drive shifts itself to neutral. What can be the cause?

Tags: mazda

My Madza Bongo Brawny is shifting itself from Drive to Neutral and sometimes does not change gears.What could be the major cause?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is the fluid level for the auto box - if it is low it can cause the symptoms you describe.